# Invalid syntax in python in range

Tags: python

this code says that this is not working. This is the error:
  File "program.py", line 2
    for i range(z):
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

This is the code:

```
z=int(input('s'))
for i range(z):
print(i)
```

Comment: You forgot the in keyword

Comment: See the sample codes from the Python docs on [for loop](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html?highlight=loop#for-statements) and [range()](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html?highlight=loop#the-range-function)

Answer (score 0):

```
z=int(input('s'))
for i in range(z):
    print(i)
```

this is the correct code

Answer (score 0):

A little indentation and missing keyword `in` in your program, try this

```
z=int(input('s'))
for i in range(z):
    print(i)
```